# rsync - Exclude a certain file extension, unless zipped

Tags: rsync

Currently I have a `cron` scheduled `.sh` script that invokes `rsync` once a week:

```
DAY0=`date -I`
DAY1=`date -I -d "1 week ago"`
rsync -aAXv --delete --link-dest=/media/backup/$DAY1 / --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/backup","/lost+found","*.SAM","*.BAM"} /media/backup/$DAY0
```

I want to exclude any file with a `.fastq` extension, but include `.fastq.gz'. This is in addition to backing up the rest of the system as per normal.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of excluding each and every filetype you *don't* want, include the ones you do want:

```
rsync ...other rsync options... \
    --include='*.fasta.gz' --exclude='*' source/ destination/
```

You may also want to use the `--one-filesystem` (`-x`) option which stops `rsync` from traversing other filesystems than the one the source directory is located on.

Alternatively, specify `*.fasta.gz` in an include pattern and then `*.fasta` in a exclude pattern afterwards.

---

For backups, I'd suggest something like `borgbackup` (possibly together with `borgmatic`) or `restic` instead of `rsync`.  These all deduplicate data which makes the backups take much less space.